# Cannot create index in Azure DocumentDB using Spring MongoTemplate

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, spring-mongodb

I just cannot create a desired index. I list existing indexes with

```
System.out.println(mongo.getCollection("User").getIndexInfo());
```

and still get only

```
[{ "v" : 1 , "key" : { "_id" : 1} , "name" : "_id_1" , "ns" : "devtest01.User"}]
```

I tried

```
mongo.getCollection("User").createIndex("syncTime");
```

and

```
Index indexDefinition = new Index("syncTime", Direction.ASC);
mongo.indexOps("User").ensureIndex(indexDefinition);
```

Result is still the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason getIndexInfo() is returning the default_id index is because DocumentDB is automatically auto-indexing everything - including MongoDB protocol support.  All paths are indexed with minimal storage and throughput costs.  For more information about DocumentDB Indexes, please refer to DocumentDB Indexing Policies at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/.

We are working on improving the response of getIndexInfo(); in the interim, you can also provide feedback directly at DocumentDB User Voice at: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb.